# Why std::cin doesn't prompt for user entry?

Tags: c++, c++11, cin

I'm trying to understand better the `std::cin` behavior.

Let's see the following code:

```
#include <iostream>                                                                                                                
int main()                                                                                                                         
{                                                                                                                                  
    char c, cin {'8'};                                                                                                             
    std::cin >> c; // enter '.'                                                                                                    
    std::cin.putback(c);                                                                                                           
    double d {88};                                                                                                                 
    std::cin >> d; // expected to fail.                                                                                            
    if (std::cin)                                                                                                                  
        std::cout << "double d = " << d << '\n';                                                                                   
    else                                                                                                                           
    {                                                                                                                              
        std::cin >> cin; // doesn't prompt user for entry neither put c into cin.                                                  
        std::cout << "cin = " << cin << '\n';                                                                                      
    }                                                                                                                              
    std::cout << "d = " << d << '\n'; // just to check.                                                                           
}
```

I wonder to get what explain the fact of `std::cin >> cin;` doesn't prompt for user entry neither attribute the value of `c` that was previously putted back into the `std::cin` stream to the variable `cin`.

Note:

- It's known that `std:: cin >>` skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)

Comment: What is the input when you run this program? I get that the first character input is `.` but what comes after that? A newline?

Comment: @user4581301 It simply initialize the variable cin with '8'. I did it just to track the content of the variable.

Comment: Because `std::cin >> d;` failed, [you need to `clear`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/clear) the failure before you can read from `std::cin` again. Without `clrear`ing, reading from `std::cin` instantly fails without any waiting around.

Comment: @john yes, I hit Enter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding this

```
else                                                                                                                           
{   
    std::cin.clear(); // new                                                                                                                           
    std::cin >> cin;                                                  
    std::cout << "cin = " << cin << '\n';                                                                                      
}
```

Because your previous input failed `std::cin` is in an error state, and all operations will fail until you clear the error state.